# Member "push" is not available in struct ... memory outside of storage

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix

Below is the contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-or-later

pragma solidity 0.6.12;
// Contracts
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;


contract test{
    mapping(address => address) public managers;

    struct tokenInfo{
      address token;
      uint256 decimals;
      uint256 amount;
  }

   struct recordInfo{
       uint time;
       tokenInfo[] tokens;
   }
   
   mapping(address => mapping(uint => recordInfo)) public record_List;

    function claim(address pool) public {    
        address manager = address(0);
        require(managers[pool] != manager,"claim is not manager"); // this `require` is necessary, if delete it, cannot compile, why?
         //record
         recordInfo storage record; // claim `storage`, compile succeed
         delete record.time;
         delete record.tokens;
         record.time = block.timestamp;
        for( uint i = 0;i < 2;i++){
            uint balance;
            tokenInfo memory token; 
            token.token = address(0);
            token.amount = balance;
            token.decimals = 18;
            record.tokens.push(token);
        }
        record_List[pool][2] = record;
    }
}
```

then I change the `recordInfo storage record` to `recordInfo memory record;`, the contract cannot compile in the remix

```
   function claim(address pool) public {    
        address manager = address(0);
        require(managers[pool] != manager,"claim is not manager"); // this `require` is necessary, if delete it, cannot compile, why?
         //record
         recordInfo memory record; // claim `memory`, cannot compile
         delete record.time;
         delete record.tokens;
         record.time = block.timestamp;
        for( uint i = 0;i < 2;i++){
            uint balance;
            tokenInfo memory token; 
            token.token = address(0);
            token.amount = balance;
            token.decimals = 18;
            record.tokens.push(token);
        }
        record_List[pool][2] = record;
    }
```

and here is the error msg :

```
from solidity:
tests/testuint.sol:38:13: TypeError: Member "push" is not available in struct test.tokenInfo memory[] memory outside of storage.
            record.tokens.push(token);
            ^----------------^
```

1. Why claimed `storage` here okay instead of  `memory`?
   **can here claim it to `memory`?**
2. If `storage` is used, why need the `require`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please always read the description of the tags you pick. For example [the `web3` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web3) says in its description: "Do not use this tag"

Comment: The smart contract that you have posted, compiles successfully.. Are you sure you shared the original smart contract?

Comment: @Kerry99 sorry not to describe the code explicitly, here is the code cannot compile :

Comment: @Kerry99
```
        address manager = address(0);
        require(managers[pool] != manager,"claim is not manager"); // this `require` is necessary, if delete it, cannot compile, why?
         //record
         recordInfo memory record; // claim `memory`, cannot compile
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why claimed storage here okay instead of memory?

This happened because `push()` method can use only for object memorized in `storage`. Thus, for object stored in `memory` you can only insert data specifying index.

More information about this topic on [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/types.html?highlight=push#arrays).

> Can here claim it to memory?

No, you cannot claim it changing storage position from `storage` to `memory`, because of all `records` are stored into storage space and you cannot update or delete their data if you change memory position.

> If storage is used, why need the require?

I think that it's a bug about compiler 0.6. Thus, if you try to change Solidity compiler from 0.6 to 0.8, the issues will show itself. Irrespective of this, the compiler say you that the record (declared into `claim()` method) don't point to any data present into `record_List` mapping. In a simple words, it wasn't initialized. In your case, you can consider to retrieve a specific element from `record_List` mapping and then you do delete and update operations.

An example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-or-later
pragma solidity 0.6.12;
// Contracts
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract test{
    mapping(address => address) public managers;

    struct tokenInfo{
      address token;
      uint256 decimals;
      uint256 amount;
  }

   struct recordInfo{
       uint time;
       tokenInfo[] tokens;
   }
   
   mapping(address => mapping(uint => recordInfo)) public record_List;

    function claim(address pool, uint idRecord) public {    
        address manager = address(0);
        require(managers[pool] != manager,"claim is not manager");
        // NOTE: I retrieve a specific element from record_List mapping using pool and idRecord parameters for querying the mapping
        recordInfo storage record = record_List[pool][idRecord];
        delete record.time;
        delete record.tokens;
        record.time = block.timestamp;
        for( uint i = 0;i < 2;i++){
            uint balance;
            tokenInfo memory token; 
            token.token = address(0);
            token.amount = balance;
            token.decimals = 18;
            record.tokens.push(token);
        }
        record_List[pool][2] = record;
    }
}
```